# Remove multiple DOM nodes at once

Tags: javascript, html

I have a row of images and I want to remove all the ones that are cut off from the page. I wrote this function:

```
var pawLineImages = document.querySelectorAll('#paw-line > img');
var pawImages = Array.prototype.slice.call(pawLineImages);
var cutOffIndex = 0;
var viewWidth = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth);
for (var i=0; i<pawImages.length; i++) {
    var elm = pawImages[i];
    var rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (rect.right - viewWidth >= 0) {
        cutOffIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
if (cutOffIndex > 0) {
    // Here I want to remove all children [cutOffIndex ... pawImages.length]
}
```

Does anyone know how I'd remove all the images that are after the `cutoffIndex` at the same time? I'm hesitant to do it in a for loop because then things might be more expensive then doing it all at once.

Comment: You have to remove them one at a time, if they don't have a common parent element that you could remove.

Answer (score 0):

Change "if" condition in the loop as below to remove the image. No need to break from the loop and then process again.

```
if (rect.right - viewWidth >= 0) {
   elm.parentNode.removeChild(elm);
}
```

OR

If there is an option of using jQuery then keep the current loop as is and after the loop use jQuery to remove all images at once.

```
// After the loop
$("#paw-line img").slice(cutOffIndex).remove();
```